# Postgresql - Constraint for only one row in table and not allow other to have flag

Tags: sqlalchemy, database-schema, psql, accounting

Currently, working on accounts module. I have one account table as following columns :

1. Account id (String)
2. Debit amount ()
3. Credit amount
4. Uncleared amount
5. Is master account (Boolean)
6. Customer_id (One to One) to Customer table

I would like to have only one master account for this table and restrict others from adding another master account to table.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE account
ADD CONSTRAINT account_unique UNIQUE (account_id);
```

I believe that Postgres will not allow you to add the constraint if your `account` table already has duplicate `account_id` entries.  If these duplicates exist, you should remove them first before doing the `ALTER TABLE`.  If you do already have duplicates, if you provide some logic maybe we can give you a query to remove them.